# Finding ways to robots feel pleasure

Tags: near-future, artificial-intelligence, computers, robots, android

Given a world where a human-like brain is synthetizable, I wonder:

A human-like artificial brain would most likely crave sensorial overwhelm. Pleasure to humans is something deeply associated with perception and the lack of it. To me, a robot like Bender is one of the best depicted AIs/Robots I have ever watched. Nihilist, looking for the next bit of pleasure he can get.

I question if a human oriented bot with way more or slightly less sensorial capacity than us would explore this concept as well. Something like a super-hearing robot getting goosebumps and enjoying ultrasounds from a noisy of a factory, or getting high when exposed to undervolting or cosmic rays.

Why would a robot search for pleasure any differently than humans? Which unique ways would they be able to get it?

Comment: Have you read any of the books in the Culture Universe books? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Culture ? AI's rule.

Comment: Try reading the bit in Douglas Adams' book *Mostly Harmless* where Ford Prefect breaks into the *Guide's* offices; it should be very enlightening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would search for different and maybe quite extreme pleasures because it can and its body isn't as fragile as humans.

Giving it human levels of emotions created by having memories and a concept of self along with hormone like mood enhancements is one way to allow the pleasure seeking.

You could essentially have it get high or feel pleasure from anything if you designed its sensory systems to be stimulated by them and allow for a high tolerance without being over loaded and damaged, unless the robot knows it can be fixed every time then it could really develop dangerous addictions.

Comment: 3 words Advanced artificial inteligence

Comment: @Topcode it thinks a given, doesn't really explain the sensory system to feel pleasure

Comment: but it does, you just add in ai for sensory intake and wire it into the main part, ai at a basic level works just like neurons in our brain so there is nothing stopping it

Comment: @Topcode true but I think what the OP is wondering is what sensory systems would they have or what could accidently pleasure it. I gave a quick example of replicate human sensations but that doesn't leave much to the imagination of what robots could feel or be given that is completely different from humans.

Comment: Thanks! I really liked the extreme aspect of it. My world may become WAY darker, but it definitely helped